# Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'UnableToLoadModule

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I want to convert pdf to jpeg i'm using (imagick) , this is my code :

```
$pdf_file   = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'pdf/cv.pdf';
$save_to    = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'pdf/demo.jpg';

$img = new imagick($pdf_file);
print_r($img);die; 
//set new format
$img->setImageFormat('jpg');

//save image file
$img->writeImage($save_to);
```

I get this exception :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'UnableToLoadModule `C:\img\img\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_PDF_.dll' in C:\wamp\www\pdf\index.php on line 6
```

Comment: Have you installed `ghostscript` to handle PDF files?

Comment: Not yet , should I just install it and it will works ?

Comment: I install ghostscript  and i got the same exception !

Comment: Ensure you have the dynamic DLL library installed, and define `MAGICK_HOME` environment variable in Apache's virtual host.